# How to test DELETE method in Spring boot using Mockito and JUnit

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit4

In Spring boot framework, I'm finding a difficulty with the controller Unit testing using JUnit and Mockito. I want to test this method. How to test DELETE Request method:

// delete application
**Controller class**

```
    @DeleteMapping("/applications")
    public String deleteApplicationByObject(@RequestBody Application application) {
        applicationService.deleteById(application.getId());
        return "Deleted";
    }
```

// delete application
**Service class**

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public String removeById(Long id) {
        dao.deleteById(id);
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
```

// delete application
**Dao class**

```
    @Override
    public void deleteById(Long id) {
        Application application = findById(id);
        em.remove(application);
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you test ANY http method on your Spring boot app? Do you use `MockMvc` or `RestAssured` - do you send it an HTTP request?

Or are you trying to call the method directly to make sure it calls `applicationService.deleteById(application.getId());`?

Comment: I'm using a mockito and Junit for unit testing and I'm using MockMvc for testing my controller methods but i'm finding a difficulty with this delete method when i'm trying to call the method applicationService.deleteById(application.getId());

Comment: can you post your test class for controller class

Comment: Here, my test Controller class @Test
 public void deleteApplication() throws Exception {  
  Mockito.when(applicationService.removeById(10001L)).thenReturn("SUCCESS");
  mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete("/applications"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk());
 }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a while i'm able to find a solution of my question which is,

**ApplicationControllerTest.class**

```
package com.spring.addapplication.test.controller;

import static org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.spring.addapplication.controller.ApplicationController;
import com.spring.addapplication.model.Application;
import com.spring.addapplication.service.ApplicationService;
import com.spring.addapplication.url.UrlChecker;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ApplicationControllerTest {

    @Mock
    ApplicationService applicationService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        initMocks(this);// this is needed for inititalization of mocks, if you use @Mock 
        ApplicationController controller = new ApplicationController(applicationService,urlChecker);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteApplication() throws Exception {      
        Mockito.when(applicationService.removeById(10001L)).thenReturn("SUCCESS");
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete("/applications", 10001L))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```